# For loop not carrying on till the end

Tags: python, for-loop

```
def HydrogenCount(Compound):

    HydrogenNo = 0
    for i in range(0, len(Compound)):
        Compound[i] == "H":
            print(Compound[i+1])
            Temp = Compound[i+1]
            Temp = int(Temp)
            HydrogenNo = HydrogenNo + Temp
            return HydrogenNo


HydrogenNo = HydrogenCount(Compound)

print ("HydrogenCount = ", HydrogenNo)
```

for an input like CH3CH2CH3 it should output hydrogen count = 8
but instead it outputs hydrogen count = 3 as it stops at the first h

Comment: indentation.  return in inside for loop

Comment: It seems that you unaccepted an accepted answer yesterday. Any reasons?

Answer (score 3):

Unindent the return statement. It's currently inside of the `for` loop and needs to be executed after. Otherwise it will only count the first.

```py
def HydrogenCount(Compound):
    HydrogenNo = 0

    for i in range(0, len(Compound)):
        Compound[i] == "H":
            print(Compound[i+1])
            Temp = Compound[i+1]
            Temp = int(Temp)
            HydrogenNo += Temp

    return HydrogenNo
```

Comment: Of course. Remember to mark it as the accepted answer if this is the one you chose to go with. I highly recommend checking out the answer @Ajeet Mishra gave below as they provide a much more complete solution.

Answer (score 1):

What if the H in the molecule has more than 9 atoms, say sugar compound C12H22O11 or glucose C6H12O6?

May I suggest you revamp the code this way:

```
import re
regex = re.compile('H([0-9]*)')

def HydrogenCount(Compound):
    try:
        return sum([int(i) for i in regex.findall(Compound)])
    except:
        return(0)
```

You may run this as:

```
print(HydrogenCount("CH3CH2CH3"))
print(HydrogenCount("C6H12O6"))
```

I still see one more flaw in the question and therefore all answers, which is how about molecules like CH3COOH, where H followed by no number implies 1 atom. So, this is the revised code to handle that too:

```
import re
regex = re.compile('H([0-9]*)')

def HydrogenCount_v2(Compound):
    try:
        res = [i if i != '' else '1' for i in regex.findall(Compound)]
        return sum([int(i) for i in res])
    except:
        return(0)

print(HydrogenCount_v2("CH3CH2CH3"))
print(HydrogenCount_v2("C6H12O6"))
print(HydrogenCount_v2("CH3COOH"))
```

Comment: oh yeah i didnt think of that, its part of the scope. ill just add an extra elif block. its for my final school project which is like a sort of compound namer. i would love if you gave me any tips.

Comment: How should i go around the CH3COOH problem?

Comment: Sure, that is a very small modification in my code. I have updated my answer for you. Do remember to give a positive rating if it helps.

Comment: Could you please explain how it works for use in other parts of the program, thank you.

Comment: Yes, here is the explanation - regex.findall() function in my code uses regular expression to identify all numbers after every H atom in a molecule and store in "res". Also, if the number is not found, the same is replaced by 1 and stored in list called "res". All the elements in res are converted to integers and added up to return the desired answer.Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor your code like this:

---

```
def calculate_hydrogen_count(compound):
    hydrogen_count = 0
    for i in range(0, len(compound) - 1):
        if compound[i] == "H":
            hydrogen_count += int(compound[i + 1])
    return hydrogen_count

compound = "CH3CH2CH3"
hydrogen_count = calculate_hydrogen_count(compound)

print ("HydrogenCount = ", hydrogen_count)
```

---

**Outputting**

8